# Debug.Assert is causing my application to exit

Tags: c#

I created a library with many utility functions to perform some tasks and placed it in it's own DLL.

Throughout the methods in this library, i've placed Debug.Assert statements to verify the state of the application.

The problem is, when the Assert is firing (the condition is false), it presents the dialog, clicking "Abort" on it causes the entire application that uses this DLL to crash.

This poses 2 questions:

1. Can this be avoided? i'd expect this to throw an exception without exiting the application.
2. How come a DLL can cause the application that loads it to exit? isn't this a security breach?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an exception thrown, why dont you just throw an exception?

Change

```
Assert(var);
```

to

```
if(!var)
  throw new Exception("var was false");
```

Assert will leave the application, assertion are here to protect you from coder's mistake. If a function should never receive a null pointer, and if it does then it would be a mistake, then an assert would be the right tool.

If you want to express an exceptionnal situation, than the exception is the tool you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I still find it hard to distinguish between where an Exception might be appropriate and when an Assertion would be.

Comment: @liortal As a rule of thumb, I generaly use assertion for programmers error. Think about it like a contract. "If you use my function, never use null pointer". This way, if it ever happens, it will fail soon (this is good) and during debug time (which is even better). Exception are usually for exceptionnal situations that might happen. You usualy want to recover from exception, while assertion are programming error and you want to fix them as soon as possible.

Answer (score 4):

The Debug.Assert is not intended to end up in release code (hence 'Debug' :) ). Choosing Abort means kill the process that raised the assert. If you choose Ignore, it should carry on, and either way this should not happen in the Release build as the Debug.Assert will be stripped out.

Edit: Here's a link to the MSDN explanation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e63efys0.aspx